# Bluestacks - ADB Disabled

Tags: adb, bluestacks

When working with Bluestacks, adb is permanently disabled. May switch off on a random action. I work through zennoposter. It is necessary to implement adb reconnection after each action. How to eliminate the constant arbitrary shutdown of adb?

adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555